# IP Address gets redirected to Sub-domain instead of Domain

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain

I have a domain lets consider example.com and sub-domain blog.example.com
Both running in the same VPS with a static IP served by Nginx, both listening at port 80.

Before adding my sub-domain whenever I entered my IP Address in the browser, the default domain was served (i.e example.com). But after adding blog subdomain, entering IP address redirect to blog.example.com instead. How can I redirect it to example.com by default? Can using a different port number for blog.example.com could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the virtual host file, make sure it's marked as `default_server`, for example:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80 default_server;
    # rest of the config
}
```

Also make sure that there's no other conf file also marked as `default_server`